# Scala regex to extract properties and associated values from a string

Tags: string, scala

Consider strings that enumerate property names each followed by an assigned value, for instance like this,

```
val s = """id=id1,desc="a description, details",location="a location""""
```

where each property value may include a quoted string with commas.

How to extract each property value into for instance

```
case class Row(id: String, location: String, desc: String)
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @revo My first try included `s.split(",")` (unsound due to commas in inner strings), and `s.split("=")` which makes the association of values and property ids hard...

Comment: What if you split at `,?[^=,]+=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split on commas outside of quotes and then on equal signs.

```
val split_str = s.split(""",(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)""").map(_.split("=").last)
```

This will give you an array of the required strings:

```
Array(id1, "a description, details", "a location")
```

If you want to remove the quotes on these strings, simply add `.replace("\"", "")` after `last`. Then simply create your class:

```
Row(split_str(0), split_str(2), split_str(1))
```

Comment: from this regex how to obtain an instance of `case class Row` ?

Comment: @elm: Added that to the answer

Comment: Your pattern is splitting on all commas. The result Array has 4 elements.

Comment: @jwvh: Had the wrong type of quote in the pattern, thanks for noticing. It should work now.

Comment: The lookahead `?=` is already non-capturing so I don't think the `?:` accomplishes anything.

Comment: How to handle the case where properties in the original string occur in an order different from the case class? (see question update)

Comment: @jwvh: That is correct. Updated the answer

Comment: @elm: Are the properties always in the same order? In that case you can just change the 1 to 2 and vice versa. Otherwise you would need to remember which property it is, using a Map would probably work just fine for that.